# which countries belong to which synchronous electricity grids?

Tags: data-request, energy

**I'm looking for a list of synchronous electricity grids, and the countries and regions that they consist of.**

Iceland is an unusual country in many ways. One of which is that its electricity grid is frequency-isolated - it has no synchronous (AC) connections with any other country's electricity grid. Wikipedia has a map of some synchronous grids (each different colour represents a different synchronous area; and yes, Denmark is indeed split across two separate grids):

[image]<sub><sub>[CC-BY-SA 3.0](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Wide_area_synchronous_grid_%28Eurasia,_Mediterranean%29.png)</sub></sub>

But it's not referenced, and only covers part of the world.

The Power Information Technology Laboratory at the University of Tennessee has [a rather funky map of real-time grid frequencies](http://powerit.utk.edu/worldmap/), and an [accompanying table](http://fnetpublic.utk.edu/tabledisplay.html), which provides more information, and covers a wider area. However, it's not entirely consistent with the wikipedia map.

So, I'm looking for a list of synchronous electricity grids, and the countries and regions that they consist of.

Comment: BTW, the disclaimer on the table data says: *The frequency values displayed here on the public website are fed from a set of sample data and do not represent the current system frequency.*

Answer (score -1):

Here's a piece of the global puzzle:

*Wide Area Monitoring* in Europe (Swissgrid, [link](https://www.swissgrid.ch/swissgrid/en/home/reliability/wam.html)) - realtime grid frequency dashboard

> For the first time the power system frequencies of several locations in Europe are being time-synchronised and made publicly accessible with a high degree of precision in one common system. The measuring devices equipped with GPS receivers in each of the substations calculate the frequency and deliver it in real time together with other time-stamped data accurate to the microsecond. These are then collected at Swissgrid in Laufenburg, superimposed on one another and published.

[image]

[image]

Comment: No, unfortunately that's not part of the answer at all. Those locations are all within the same synchronous grid, as can be seen in the picture in the question.

Comment: [When should I vote down?](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-down)